# Extend partition beyond 2TB limit

Tags: centos, centos7

How can I expand a partition + fs to 4TB in CentOS? It's currently XFS and 900GB, without LVM.

I've tried using gparted in the Ubuntu LiveCD, but I'm given an error that this partition cannot be expanded above 2TB.

*Edit: How to change from MBR to GPT without data loss, and have the system boot correctly after?

Comment: I feel like a question such as 'How to change from MBR to GPT without data loss' is an easily Googleable one..

Answer (score 0):

If your disk is partitioned with MBR tables, this is not possible, as 2 TB is the limit for that system. You need a GPT table in that case.